# Какой знак препинания нужно поставить перед "кто-то"?

Tags: пунктуация

Многие россияне и жители ближнего зарубежья думают, наверное, что Москва -- гигантская кладовая, набитая едой и другими земными благами, и стремятся попасть в неё (?) кто-то, чтобы просто прокормиться, а кто-то и чтобы "наесть толстые бока."

Comment: Перед вторым "чтобы" запятая не нужна? Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многие россияне и жители ближнего зарубежья думают, наверное, что Москва — гигантская кладовая, набитая едой и другими земными благами, и стремятся попасть в неё: кто-то — чтобы просто прокормиться, а кто-то и для того, чтобы "наесть толстые бока".

Первое тире однозначно необходимо, сравнить: Хотя каждому свое: кто-то хочет заработать, а кто-то ― чтобы на нем заработали.

Также в конце сделана корректировка неблагозвучной конструкции.

Comment: Спасибо, Vera !

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

*Многие россияне и жители ближнего зарубежья думают, наверное, что Москва -- гигантская кладовая, набитая едой и другими земными благами, и стремятся попасть в неё: кто-то, чтобы просто прокормиться, а кто-то -- и чтобы "наесть толстые бока".*

Вместо запятой после первого ***кто-то*** возможно тире.

Comment: Спасибо, slava1947!